# Generate API docs with Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

I am writing Javadocs for a project I am working on, and would like to leverage the `@link` tag to link each endpoint to the javadoc generated for each method.

Ideally, I'd like to do something simliar to this:

```
POST /api/resources      calls {@link Resource#getAll()     Resource@getAll}
GET  /api/resources/{id} calls {@link Resource#getById(int) Resource#getById}
```

I'm very open to any solutions that are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven has a feature that allows you to write HTML markup in `src/main/javadoc/overview.html` and it will process all Javadoc tags and write the output to the main Javadoc page.

This works pretty well when if you use markdown to generate the overview.html page